# Restore a deleted python standard library file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I deleted a file:

```
rm /usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py
```

This is part of python's standard library. How can I get this back? `pip3 install` says it cannot find the module.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling python with the installer

Comment: Did you install Python via a package manager, or a download from python.org or similar?

Comment: Last time I checked subprocess isn't in the python standard library...

Comment: @xilpex yeah it is... https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @wjandrea solved. Went to the link and downloaded the source file and put it back in the dir.

Comment: Oh cool! python 3.8 has it built in!

Comment: @Kunseok Awesome! I recommend you [post your own answer](/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: @xilpex It's been in the standard lib [since 2.4](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-324-new-subprocess-module)... Maybe you're thinking of something else.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know that-- thanks for informing me! :)

Comment: @Kunseok You can download the file from the repository, but make sure you select the right tag in order to prevent compatibility issues (check via `python --version`). For example: `wget -O /usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py "https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v$(python --version | cut -c 8-)/Lib/subprocess.py"`.